# React JS - Uncaught TypeError: states.map is not a function // useEffect problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

[The initial output of the page load is seen at the top and then a second load returns an array of data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLh6W.png) So when calling the map function on states.map I get the Uncaught TypeError: states.map is not a function. Which I don't understand why. Also the API call only happens when the page is reloaded in some way that's not the initial load. I probably just don't understand useEffect. For that the console.log of the state just gives nothing. I would really appreciate any help!

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Row, Container } from "../components/Grid";
import SiteNav from "../components/SiteNav";
import CoronaCard from "../components/CoronaCard";
import covidAPI from "../utils/covidAPI";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import "./style.css"



function CoronaTravelNews() {

    // Setting our component's initial state
    const [states, setStates] = useState([])

    // Load all books and store them with setBooks
    useEffect(() => {
        loadStates()
    }, [])

    // Loads all books and sets them to books
    function loadStates() {
        covidAPI.getCovidInfo()
            .then(res =>
                setStates(res),
                console.log("This is the response: "),
                console.log("This is the current state: "),
                console.log(states)
            )
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };



    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="md-12">
                        <SiteNav />
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col size="md-12">

                        {states.map(function (state, i) {
                            return (<CoronaCard
                                key={i}
                                province={state.data.key.state}
                                date={state.data.key.date}
                                cases={state.data.key.positive}
                                newCases={state.data.key.positiveIncrease} />)
                        })}

                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <Footer />
                <br></br>
            </Container >
        </div >
    );
}

export default CoronaTravelNews;
```

Comment: it seems that `covidAPI.getCovidInfo` returns "nothing" as you call it - therefore that reflects the console log that returns "nothing". What am I missing? Please validate the return from that API call is actually an array.

Comment: most likely `res` is an object rather than a array.

Comment: Also, `console.log` right after `setState` logs the state of the current render unchanged by the setState call. The updated state will only be available on the next render and since `useEffect` runs *after* the first render `states` will be empty until the next render triggered by the setState. Standard practice is to conditionally render the first render awaiting the fetch. `{ states.length && states.map(...`

Comment: Could you add what is the output of console.log(res)?

Comment: @buzatto How would I get it to return an array then?  as it is return an object.

Comment: @pilchard That makes a lot of sense so the console log is actually returning the previous state technically. Can you explain the states.length a little more.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I added a picture of the console output initially and after refreshing the page's state. The `res` does return an array when I try to console log it directly I get an error saying that it's not defined though so inferring from the fact that the state is changed to an array of data.

Comment: is theere a typo in the code why is there a space between function and the ( 
`function (s`

Comment: @sonali that's valid syntax...

Comment: try ` states && states.map(` instead of `states.map(` that way it will check if there is states

Comment: I added `states && states.map` and got `TypeError: states.map is not a function`

Comment: setStates(res.data);

Comment: res in your API call is probably not an array. What does the `res` data structure look like?

Comment: @ToddSkelton That was suggested above and it works now. Thanks to everyone's suggestions the issue is now closed! THANKS!

Comment: @KelvinHong Thanks! That worked and now with all the suggestions everything renders thank you so much!

Comment: To answer your question about `states.length && ` used in a ternary – if the array is empty (length 0) the ternary casts the length to a boolean and returns `false` since 0 is falsy and won't render, otherwise it returns true (so long as the array exists).

Comment: @pilchard Thanks for that I'm a javascript noob and that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

in your return statement, you should add this

```
return (
<div>
    {states.length==0 
    ? (<p>Loading ... </p>)    //add a loader or return null when states = []
    : (<Container> ...your jsx... </Container>)    // else, return your jsx
    }
</div>
);
```